# How could you make realistic Frostwalker boots?

Tags: water, ice, freezing

In Minecraft, as you might know, you can enchant boots with Frostwalker, which freezes water as you walk over it. I've been wondering if this would be possible in real life, and if so, how?
My idea is a tank of supercooled water on your back, with jets built into your boots to spray it. (Moving this to Engineering)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because movie special effects are often unrealistic, Special effects are meant to be stories, not how the world really works. Trying to figure out the physics behind them is just misunderstanding physics.

Comment: I disagree with mmesser's view that figuring out the physics behind a special effect *as if it was real* is a mistake. It is often the case that there is no possible physics that could produce it, but even explaining why (as g.s. answer below) reveals useful physical constraints. I do think the question is an engineering question, though: there are no real constraints on how one could try to solve it, and that makes proposals for actual solutions somewhat arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Normally if you walk on ice you're supported by a thin layer across a very large area, and the structural strength of ice is what supports you. If you were just freezing water under your feet, you'd need to be supported by buoyancy. Ice is about 90% as dense as water, so you'd have to freeze about ten times your displacement in water with every step to support yourself with the buoyant force.

The energy cost of this, if the water was already at 0 degrees and you mass 70 kg, would be

$334 J/g * 70000 g * 10 = 233.8 MJ$

The latent heat of vaporization of liquid nitrogen is about 0.2 MJ/kg, so you'd need to jet well over a thousand kilograms of LN2 into the lake for every step you took, which, aside from the engineering challenge of bringing thousands of kilos of cryogenic fluid with you without increasing your own effective weight, would be instantly fatal to you and everyone around you.

Comment: Don't neglect the heat capacity of the liquid nitrogen, which is ~$\mathrm{2 \,kJ/kg/K}$.